# Hatcher 2.1 Problem 17 (a)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm only interested in the case where $A$ is a single point and $X=S^2$ for the following question from Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology.

Question:  Compute the homology of groups $H_n(X,A)$ when $X$ is $S^2$ or $T^2$ and $A$ is a finite set of points in $X$.

Answer Attempt:  In Hatcher p.g. 117 it says you can think of the relative homology $H_n(X,A)$ as the measure of the difference between the two groups $H_n(X)$ and $H_n(A)$.  Taking that literally, let $x\in X$, then $H_n(S^2\setminus {x})\cong H_n(\mathbb{R^2})\cong 0$

EDIT:  Actually, if I were to take the statement, "you can think of the relative homology $H_n(X,A)$ as the measure of the difference between the two groups $H_n(X)$ and $H_n(A)$.", from Hatcher literally it would be more correct to note that since $H_2(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2(A)=H_1(A)=0$ their difference is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The equation in your attempt doesn't follow at all. The group $H_n(X, A)$ is not the difference or quotient of $H_n(X)$ and $H_n(A)$; they fit into a long exact sequence. Homology does not commute with taking quotients; the relative groups $H_n(X, A)$ indicate that failure.

Comment: OK, so I should just stick with the conventional approach, namely, $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to H_2(X,A)\to 0 \implies H_2(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Right. Hatcher's remark is just a fuzzy statement for intuition; it shouldn't be taken literally. (For one thing, the situation gets more complicated with torsion.)

Comment: one can think $S^2/A=S^2\bigvee\vee _{(|A|-1)}S^1$.